# Dollars or euros to South Korea?

Tags: money, payment-cards, south-korea

Is it better to bring Dollars or Euros? Is it possible to pay with creditcards (mastercard or visa) in most places? Like hotels and such. What is best to do, get cash or pay with creditcard?

Comment: I edited it ....

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to take Won? Where are you from, what currency do you already have (it's probably not worth turning euros to dollars to won for example)

Comment: Denmark. We have danish kroner, but can't get won in my bank. Only euros and dollars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bring whatever suits you best. If you live in the Euro area there is no point in converting Euros into Dollars to convert them later into Won. You will loose twice from the exchange. Euros can as easily be exchanged into Wons as Dollars can be. Buying Won in Europe can be cumbersome and is not worth the effort.

Credit cards (MasterCard and Visa) are also widely accepted. You can even use them to withdraw money from automated teller machines (ATM).

I usually bring a bunch of Euros, and exchange them progressively into Won. And I use my credit card intensively. This way, I end up using all my Wons and go home with some Euros in my pocket. But there are alternative valuable strategies.

Comment: Just a note: It's 'Won', not 'Wons'.

Comment: *You can even use them to withdraw money from automated teller machine*.  Are there are any places in the world where ATMs do *not* accept credit cards?

Comment: @gerrit Countries where credit is not really allowed perhaps? Although it's normally a pretty bad idea to use a credit card at an ATM.

Comment: Indeed, there may be high fees. But that's the price you have to pay for not carrying cash with you.

Answer (score 2):

You can bring Dollars or Euros with you while visiting South Korea. You can also use master card in shopping in South Korea.

Comment: Or Visa.  And some banks (I use Schwab) refund all ATM fees and give a far better exchange rate than any place whose main source of revenue is exchange rates.

Comment: To find out specific rates for using a visa debit card in an ATM or POS, see https://www.visa.com.au/travel-with-visa/exchange-rate-calculator.html/   And if your bank makes you put anything other than zero in the bank fee box, consider finding another bank.